# CSS: Hidden elements still take up space on printed output

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser, printing

I'm using css to only print a section of a page:

```
    body {
 visibility:hidden;
    }
    .print {
     visibility:visible;
     background-color: white;
     margin: 0;
    }
```

The section above the element I want to print gets properly hidden in the print output, however it still takes up the area of space. I tested this by making a long vertical list of words. In the print output the same area of white space occurs without the words and then the element output occurs. This problem occurs on chrome and mozilla only. I've also tested the browser's margin options and that's not the problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You want `display:none` not `visibility:hidden`. The latter makes the element invisible, but doesn't remove it from the document flow.

Comment: Thanks my CSS is weak. I'm guessing it's a bad idea to display: none the whole body? Should I add what I want to print to the page or remove what I don't want?

Comment: I think `display:none` on `body` would be a bad idea, but I've never tried it! Probably best to `display:none` on only the non-printing elements (you could add a non-printing class to them in the markup).

Comment: And how I did't think of this!? But must apply it individually to elements and not to the whole <body>. <body> visibility:hidden is fine though, just incomplete. Thanks anyway. I was looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

Use `@media` for printing. For example:

```
@media print {
  * {display: none;} /*or if you want only the body*/ body {display: none;}
  .print {display: block;}
}
```

(only a rough example. an actual stylesheet should include all elements of a page instead of wildcards)

Then the stylesheet is only used when printing, or print previewing.

Answer (score 2):

if we want `display:inline-block` or `display:block` along with visibility hidden.

Then we can use follwing css as a workaround.

```
{
    visibility:hidden
    width:0px;
    height:0px 
}
```

Comment: I was running into issues where it would print 5 black pages because the body was just hidden. Setting height to 0 worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:none;`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `display: none;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

use display:none; as you want to display only print and no part of body.

Answer (score -1):

Even `visibility:collapse;` does it!  :)

Comment: `visibility: collapse` is the same as `visibility: hidden` if applied to non-table elements